# Devextreme causes an Error code TS6053 - index.d.ts not found

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, devexpress, devextreme

Each time i compile my angular 5 app on visual studio, I get this error:

**Error code TS6053 - file index.d.ts not found**

Now. The file actually not exist and the error does not give any info about where is required this file. Also searching "info.d.ts" in the entire solution does not bring me anything.

What could be the reason of this error?

**INFOS**

- I'm **not using angular-cli**
- I'm working on visual studio 2017
- Typescript version: "^2.6.2"

**UPDATE #1**

It looks like the issue is related to some npm packages, but the file index.d.ts is mentioned in a lot of them and i can't understand what package is actually causing this error.

Got any solution?

**UPDATE #2**
I've found that the issue is caused by devexpress' devextreme package.

The package.json contains the following: `"typings": "/index.d.ts",`

If i change it to: `"typings": "./index.d.ts",` (added the dot), the error vanishes from my compiling error window, but i can't start my app anymore.

So...found the error, but created a new one!

The question is still the same: got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've made it!

The solution was simply to **update my project Typescript version via npm**.

Hope this can be helpful!

Comment: Very helpful! It would be even better to include how to update project Typescript version via npm.

Comment: With the same compile error, I can still run the web application as normal and cannot see any obvious problems. However, I did the update anyway. After the update, the compile error still exits.